# Does Apache Olingo java library support OData V3?

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I need to consume OData V3 services from Java.

Apache Olingo is the only active open source project for OData. But it does not seem to support OData V3. I googled and found some discussion of Olingo V4 actually supporting OData V3 through method such as

```
ODataClientFactory.getEdmEnabledClientV3(...)
```

But I couldn't find such method in the current Olingo Java library.

And two other Java libraries for OData V3 seem to be dormant:

- ODataJClient, whose github page says that it is now part of Olingo project.
- odata4j

Does Apache Olingo support OData V3 or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no released version of the V3 Olingo client. Your best shot right now is to use the ODataJClient from github. The Olingo project is currently working on the new V4 Client and Server.

The method you found was part of an early beta where Olingo tried to support V3 and V4 services in one library. Due to the large differences between the V3 and V4 protocol it was decided to have separate libraries for V3 and V4. V4 has been released recently and V3 is currently on a separate branch.

If you would like to contribute to Olingo you can always write to the users list: `user@olingo.apache.org`.